# tensorflow only predicts '[UNK]' characters

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am trying to generate text in a certain style using tensorflow, and even when I copy and paste the code from the tensorflow website it only predicts unknown characters even though there is a mask to prevent this. I'm thinking it has something to do with the version of python I'm running (3.9.15) since it doesnt even work with their code and dataset.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

```
class OneStep(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, model, chars_from_ids, ids_from_chars, temperature=1.0):
    super().__init__()
    self.temperature = temperature
    self.model = model
    self.chars_from_ids = chars_from_ids
    self.ids_from_chars = ids_from_chars

    # Create a mask to prevent "[UNK]" from being generated.
    skip_ids = self.ids_from_chars(['[UNK]'])[:, None]
    sparse_mask = tf.SparseTensor(
        # Put a -inf at each bad index.
        values=[-float('inf')]*len(skip_ids),
        indices=skip_ids,
        # Match the shape to the vocabulary
        dense_shape=[len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary())])
    self.prediction_mask = tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse_mask)

  @tf.function
  def generate_one_step(self, inputs, states=None):
    # Convert strings to token IDs.
    input_chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(inputs, 'UTF-8')
    input_ids = self.ids_from_chars(input_chars).to_tensor()

    # Run the model.
    # predicted_logits.shape is [batch, char, next_char_logits]
    predicted_logits, states = self.model(inputs=input_ids, states=states,
                                          return_state=True)
    # Only use the last prediction.
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits[:, -1, :]
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits/self.temperature
    # Apply the prediction mask: prevent "[UNK]" from being generated.
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits + self.prediction_mask

    # Sample the output logits to generate token IDs.
    predicted_ids = tf.random.categorical(predicted_logits, num_samples=1)
    predicted_ids = tf.squeeze(predicted_ids, axis=-1)

    # Convert from token ids to characters
    predicted_chars = self.chars_from_ids(predicted_ids)

    # Return the characters and model state.
    return predicted_chars, states
```

I lifted this straight from their tutorial and tried to run it in my enviroment and it just predicted '[UNK]'

I'm running a mac M1 with the latest version of tensorflow. So, that may also be an issue.

PLEASE HELP!!

Tutorial for reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation

Comment: For how many epochs you trained your model ?

Comment: I’ve gone up to as many as 40 with no luck. My suspicion is that the mask isn’t being applied properly, but I’m really new to this. So, that could be wrong.

Comment: Please tell if you managed to solve the problem? Is it linked by unicode characters?